# What owner node should the quorum drive belong to

Tags: clustering, failover

Using windows fail over clustering on a two or three node cluster.  What owner node should the quorum drive be owned by?

During my fail over testing, i can jump from node 1 to 2 and 2 to 1, but the quorum drive seems to 'stick' a different node than the active node.

I'm sure its a 'depends' kind of question, but should the quorum drive be owned by the active node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using windows fail over clustering on a two or three node cluster. What owner node should the quorum drive be owned by?

> I'm sure its a 'depends' kind of question, but should the quorum drive be owned by the active node?

Yes and no, on the it depends. Generically, it doesn't really matter as a properly setup witness on a properly setup cluster won't typically have any issues when nodes go up and down. There will be arbitration and this will have a winner (or not due to other factors).

There are somewhat (but not entirely) pedantic issues brought up around how this works, but typically it really doesn't matter.